# WPF .NET and amazon Database

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm a beginner with .NET using WPF and I want gain some experience by creating a new app using database. I want to create a .NET/WPF desktop application for sharing multimedia content.

The idea simple, there is a client app on each windows computer, a relational database with users, stats and contents. When someone shared a content, he has to link the content with users, only theses users can be able to download the content. In same time, when I add a content, a notification is send to linked users and if the client app is available, the content is automatically download.
For the desktop app I want to use .NET with WPF but for the database and for the multimedia contents I want to use Amazon Web Service like Amazon RDS (with mysql), Amazon Lambda and Amazon SNS for notifications, Amazon S3 to store content and maybe AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I think it’s only for webapp.

My Question is:  can we use Amazon Web Services easily with .NET/WPF? Can I just use AWS API or I have to host a Linux instance and to write a server on it?
 If someone has already done an application with the couple (.NET/WPF, AWS).

I’ll be happy if (s)he could share his experience and tell me how I can use the AWS APPI direct into my client app.

English is not my mother tongue and I hope to be understood by everybody  
Thanks a lot 
Psykomusic

Comment: There seems to be an amazon AWS SDK for .NET you could use. https://aws.amazon.com/es/documentation/sdk-for-net/

Comment: I would suggest you start by reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx it shows you the primary concept that WPF is build around which is your front end and data model shouldn't directly connect, if your data comes from Amazon, or a File on the hard drive shouldn't matter to your front end